# Make "Cell A" check value of "cell B" then return value of "Cell C"

Tags: excel

Been looking around and can't find anything for it. I am still very new to all this so I apologize if its a simple solution.

This is an example of what I was trying to do:

```
=IF(E4=True,0,=I16)
```

Where `E4` is a list of names and I16 is the sum of a set of items.
What I want is if `E4 = True` then show value of `I16` , if not show `0`

All my calculations are done elsewhere this is just a summary that I want the option to either turn on or off by changing the value of E4 from true to false.

Hopefully I explained it well.

Comment: `=IF(E4=True,0,I16)` should do it. But why do you say it (E4) can be both a list of names, and true or false?

Comment: Actually, you can simply use `=IF(E4,I16,0)`. (Just remember that the second argument of an `IF` is the result of the first argument is true.

Answer (score 0):

the syntax of the excel if statement is `=IF(LOGICAL_TEST,[value if true],[value if false])` so there is no need for another `=` within the syntax.

You will need `"` around anything you want as text in the form of:

`=IF(A1 = "Bob","Robert","Not Bob")`

but to show values of other cells you simply need the cell name:

`=IF(A1=32,b1,c1)`

If you want to nest the logic with another if statement you place the `IF(logic,[true],[false])` within the true or false location as such:

`=IF(A1 = 5,IF(b2>a1,b1,"less than"),c1)`

Comment: Thanks, I had tried this earlier and it didn't work so I am guessing I did something wrong. Works perfectly now.